# That which I am 2 - who are we?

Tags: riddle

Who am I?  I am many things.

> I am the moon.
>
> I am a physician,
> purifying the waters about me.
>
> I am the bane of evil
> in the depths of the night.
>
> I am the gateway to a realm contrary,
> though none may enter it through me.
>
> I am the watchful record of the past.
>
> I am a rain-bringer.
>
> I carry the lightning, though people tend
> to prefer to ask my sister to do so.
> Well, that's fair; she is cheaper to hire.

Oh, no, I'm not an only child.
I have two siblings.

> My younger sister came from the Mediterranean, and it shows.
> She has a wonderful tan, though sometimes
> she looks a little green around the gills.
>
> My elder brother, on the other hand, is favored by all.
> This, despite the fact he can't even say his first name,
> at least not without stuttering.

I also have many cousins.
Two, in particular,
might be mistaken for me,
at least for a moment.

> The first of these - well, he has a hellish stench.
> And he likes to tarnish my reputation.  Not fun.
> Still, we just have sound-alike names.
> He doesn't pretend to be me.
>
> No, that's left to the other one.
> She looks a lot like me, I'll admit,
> although she's much more athletic.
> And she can make herself useful at times,
> but be warned; don't get involved with her.
> She's pure poison, after all.

So, now that I've told you about myself and my family,
do you think you can tell me who we really are?

**Who am I?  Who are my siblings?  And who are my cousins?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are

> silver

I am the moon.

> Silver is traditionally associated with the moon.

I am a physician, 
purifying the waters about me.

> Silver is used to disinfect water.

I am the bane of evil
in the depths of the night.

> Silver bullets are supposed to kill werewolves.

I am the gateway to a realm contrary,
though none may enter it through me.

> Mirrors are made with the process of silvering.

I am the watchful record of the past.

> Gramophone records are called "silver platters".

I am a rain-bringer.

> Silver iodide is used for cloud seeding.

I carry the lightning, though people tend
to prefer to ask my sister to do so.
Well, that's fair; she is cheaper to hire.

> Silver is a good conductor of electricity, but typically copper is used instead.

---

Your siblings are

> copper and gold

My younger sister came from the Mediterranean, and it shows.
She has a wonderful tan, though sometimes 
she looks a little green around the gills.

> Copper is named after the Mediterrean island of Cyprus. It has a red-orange color but can develop a green patina.

My elder brother, on the other hand, is favored by all.
This, despite the fact he can't even say his first name,
at least not without stuttering.

> Gold is used to denote 1st place. The Latin word for gold (*aurum*) is derived from a reduplicated Proto-Indo-European root **h₂é-h₂us-o-*.

---

The cousins mentioned are

> sulfur and mercury

The first of these - well, he has a hellish stench.
And he likes to tarnish my reputation.  Not fun.
Still, we just have sound-alike names.
He doesn't pretend to be me.

> Sulfur (alternative name *brimstone*) is associated with Hell. It is known for the bad odor of its compounds, particularly hydrogen sulfide. Tarnished silver develops a coating of silver sulfide.

No, that's left to the other one.
She looks a lot like me, I'll admit,
although she's much more athletic.
And she can make herself useful at times,
but be warned; don't get involved with her.
She's pure poison, after all.

> Mercury is also called quicksilver and has a similar appearance to silver, but it is liquid. Mercury and its compounds are toxic.